# Scraped page only renders in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mapbox

I've got a MapBox page I'm trying to save as an image and I have it working fine in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer but I don't get any elements rendered in Chrome or Firefox??? When I run it in debug for Firefox I can see the elements populate and the page actually displays properly but if I run it without stepping through the code it still comes up empty. No errors or warnings in the console for either Chrome or Firefox??? Any ideas? Seems like it might be some hidden security issue?

```
function ShowMap() {
var OpenWindow = window.open('ExportMap.html', '_blank', 'width=1500,height=1500,resizable=1');
var imgMap = map.getCanvas().toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
OpenWindow.document.getElementById('imgExportMap').src = imgMap;
var objLegend = document.getElementById('legend');
var divLeg = OpenWindow.document.getElementById('divLegend');
divLeg.innerHTML = objLegend.innerHTML;
}

<body>
<div id="divRow" class="divRow">
<div id="divCarrierInfo">
<button id="btnSave" class="btnMapAction" onclick="SavePageAsImg()" type="button">Save As</button>
<button id="btnPrint" class="btnMapAction" onclick="window.print()" type="button">Print</button</div>
<div id="divTitle">
<textarea id="taTitle">"Replace this text with your map title"</textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div id="divMapElements">
<div id="divLegend"></div>
<div id="divMap">
<img id="imgExportMap" src="" alt="None" title="Test">
</div>
</div>
<img id="result-image" src="" alt="None" title="ExportMap">
</body>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for this? Mapbox offers a pretty robust Static Images API for capturing static map images, even with custom styles and overlays: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-images/. There are also some guidelines on proper usage of static maps, so saving an image of a Mapbox page might be problematic in terms of proper data usage and attribution: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/static-maps/.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out. The primary driver for my work was a requirement for a user created Map Title.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to the [map option](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map): `options.preserveDrawingBuffer`. If set to `true`, the map’s canvas can be exported to a PNG using `map.getCanvas().toDataURL()`. This is `false` by default as a performance optimization.

That being said, I'd recommend looking into [Mapbox's Static Images API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-images) as mentioned in my comment on the post. This API provides the intended way of generating a static image of a map, and will likely be more performant than exporting a PDF of the map's canvas object. You noted that you're interested in including a user-generated map title -- this can be included with the Static Images API. As noted in the optional parameters for the [retrieve a static map from a style endpoint](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-a-static-map-from-a-style), the `addLayer` parameter allows you to add a [Mapbox style layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/) to the map. For text, you'll want to add a [`symbol` layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol), and set the [`text-field`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-text-field) layout property to the title value provided by the user.